# 'ToString()' takes 1 arguments when DateTime?(Nullable) type I uses

Tags: c#, datetime, nullable

[DateTime? Nullable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dal28.jpg)When I use DateTime? as Nullable type "ToString("dd MMMMyyyy " + "(HH:mm tt)")" error appears.

Comment: What string did you expect in case your value was `null` (i.e. if not `HasValue`)?

Comment: string should be empty or null

Comment: Then use the answer in the other (of which this is a duplicate) thread, and say `""` instead of their `"<not available>"`.

Answer (score 2):

You must use something like this. I've added null check as suggested by [Colin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8152/colin-mackay)

```
if(dateVariable.HasValue)
  string dateString = dateVariable.Value.ToString("dd MMMMyyyy " + "(HH:mm tt)");
```

`Nullable<T>` is a generc and it wraps object. You must access it via `.Value` property.

Comment: Just remember to check for null first.

Comment: @ColinMackay, Good catch. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Robert If I uses this then i gets an error of 
"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." 
on this line :
date = DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["UpdatedOn"].ToString());

Comment: @tahahanif it might be that `dt.Rows[0]["UpdatedOn"].ToString()` holds unsupported format value