# How to format Duration with ToString()?

Tags: c#, datetime, tostring, duration

When trying to format a duration with ToString() I get the following message `'No Overload for method 'ToString()' takes 1 arguments`. I have found previous threads on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33371527/no-overload-for-method-tostring-takes-1-arguments-when-casting-date) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39328689/tostring-takes-1-arguments-when-datetimenullable-type-i-uses); however, these threads are for a nullable DateTime and both suggest using `myDatetime.Value.ToString()`, which I have tried in the example below, but still receive the same message.

```
    public System.Windows.Duration? MyDuration { get; set; }

    public string MyDurationString
    {
        get => (MyDuration.HasValue) ? MyDuration.Value.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss.fff") : null;
        set => MyDuration = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ?
                TimeSpan.Zero : TimeSpan.Parse(value);
    }
```

Comment: What is the `Duration` type here? Could you provide a [mcve] rather than just a snippet? (It would be simpler just to construct the duration and then format it - no need for nullable properties etc.)

Comment: Why you don't use `TimeSpan`?

Comment: If this is a Noda Time duration, it would be good to add the nodatime tag - and then basically you need to pass an `IFormatProvider`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: If this *is* a Noda Time question, the answer is "because Noda Time is a superior date/time API to DateTime/TimeSpan/DateTimeOffset" :)

Comment: The overload you're looking is for the `DateTime` type so it's only going to work if you use it to convert a `DateTime` into a `string`.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Windows.System.Duration , I'll clarify in the OP

Comment: @ayylmao1234: well, then there is no overload of [`ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.duration.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Duration_ToString) that takes arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know this type, but it seems that the WPF `Duration` doesn't have a [`ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.duration.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Duration_ToString) that takes arguments. But it has a property [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.duration.timespan?view=netframework-4.7.2) and you could use that:

```
get => MyDuration.HasTimeSpan ? MyDuration.TimeSpan.ToString("hh':'mm':'ss'.'fff") : null;
```

Comment: Note: According to documentation, a Duration might also not have a `TimeSpan` - it would be wise to check the `HasTimeSpan` property first.